Installing MATlink
Me and ChatGPT have tried unsuccesfully for three hours to install MATlink manually from http://matlink.org/#installation  I was wondering if someone succeeded recently (since it seems this is not available on Github anymore, there seem to be no more paclecs to be installed by an Install Manager)

Reference
http://matlink.org/#installation
https://github.com/szhorvat/MATLink-MEX
Steps
Below is my steps (Windows 11 (64 bit), Mathematica 14.0, MATLAB R2024a):

download the MATLink.zip file from wayback machine
run SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}], then unzip the MATLink.zip in this folder.
add MATLAB\R2024a\bin and MATLAB\R2024a\bin\win64 to Path
open mathematica, open matlab

TEST
Needs["MATLink`"]

?MATLink`*
OpenMATLAB[]  (* If succeeded, you will see mengine(pyadg_shm) process running in the task bar *)

MEvaluate, evaluate matlab script
MEvaluate["mat = magic(4)"]
MEvaluate["
exist('mat_tr','var')
isequal(mat', mat_tr)
"]


t = MScript["mytiming", "tic;
for i=1:1000
eig(mat*mat_tr);
end
toc"]
MEvaluate[t]

MGet, to get matlab workspace variable, transfer it to mathematica variable.
MSet, to get mathematica variable, transfer it to matlab workspace variable.
mat = MGet["mat"];
MSet["mat_tr", Transpose[mat]];

MFunction, use matlab's function like mathematica function.
magic = MFunction["magic"];
magic[4] // MatrixForm


eig = MFunction["eig"];
eig[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 8}}]
Eigenvalues[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 8}}] // N


eigsystem = MFunction["eig", "OutputArguments" -> 2];
eigsystem[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 8}}] // Map[MatrixForm, #] &
Eigensystem[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 8}}] // N // 
 Map[MatrixForm, #] &



imagesc = MFunction["imagesc", "Output" -> False];
data = Import[
    "ExampleData/ozonemap.hdf", {"Datasets", "TOTAL_OZONE"}][[20 ;;, 
    All]];
imagesc[data];

Finally
CloseMATLAB[]
DisconnectEngine[]    (* I can not find DisconnectMATLAB[], I guess it is deprecated. *)
MATLink`Developer`CleanupTemporaryDirectories[]


Everything seems fine (well, I have MatlabR2024b), but test fails Needs::nocont: Context MATLink` was not created when Needs was evaluated.

@florin Make sure: run SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}], then unzip the MATLink.zip in this folder.

In the end, it was something amazingly stupid, the "Russian dolls extractor". When I extract, my extractor creates inside the MATlink folder another folder called MATlink. When I collapsed this structure, everything worked out.
